# how to pass string to bash command as a parameter

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string variable which contains a loop.

```
loopVariable="for i in 1 2 3 4 5 do echo $i done"
```

I want to pass this variable to a bash command inside the shell script. But i am always getting an error

```
bash $loopVariable
```

i've tried also

```
bin/bash $loopVariable
```

But it also doesn't work. Bash treats the string giving me an error. But theoretically it execute it. I am not sure what am i doing wrong

```
bash: for i in 1 2 3 4 5 do echo $i done: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried to use this approach using while loop. But getting the same error

```
i=0 
loopValue="while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do make -j15 clean && make -j15 done"
bash -c @loopValue
```

when I use bash -c "@loopValue"  i get following error

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

and when i use just use bash -c @loopValue

```
[: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Your `while` loop should be  `while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do make -j15 clean && make -j15; done`, (missing `;` before `done`), and your bash command: `bash -c $loopValue`, not `bash - c @loopValue`.

Comment: now its giving ` -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: My bad... double quote the variable: `bash -c "$loopValue"`

Comment: it now complains about unexpected done token

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the `-c` option to read the command from an argument. The following should work:

```
$ loopVariable='for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $i; done'
$ bash -c "$loopVariable"
1
2
3
4
5
```

from man bash:

> ```
>   -c         If the -c option is present, then commands are read from  the
>              first non-option argument command_string.  If there are argu‐
>              ments after the command_string,  they  are  assigned  to  the
>              positional parameters, starting with $0.
> ```

Another way is to use the standard input:

```
bash <<< "$loopVariable"
```

---

Regarding the updated command in the question, even if we correct the quoting issues, and the fact that the variable is not exported, you are still left with an infinite loop since `$i` never changes:

```
loopValue='while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]; do make -j15 clean && make -j15; done'
i=0 bash -c "$loopValue"
```

But it would almost always be better to use a function as in [@Kenavoz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487365).

Comment: and what does -c do?

Comment: It allows bash to read the command to be executed from the argument list, instead of the standard input.

Comment: can i use the same approach with while loop?

Comment: @KvyatkovskySergey: Sure, why not? Any valid bash command (or list of commands) is accepted

Comment: i am assigning the loopVariable value to while [ 0 -lt 3 ] do make -j15 clean && make -j15 done but getting the same error

Comment: @KvyatkovskySergey: Edit your question to include your actual code, and the error message you get

Comment: @KvyatkovskySergey: I tried to fix your second example in the edit in my answer, but it looks like the code would better placed in a function rather than a string, like in Kenavoz' answer

Comment: Wow its working but it seems line the loop became infinite

Comment: @KvyatkovskySergey: It's infinite because you never change `$i`

Comment: i have change it to this while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]; do make -j15 clean && make -j15 ((i++)); done   but get unexpected token error now

Comment: @KvyatkovskySergey: You should separate commands with a semicolon when they are on the same line: `loopValue='while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]; do make -j15 clean && make -j15;  ((i++)); done'`

Comment: can i ask what is the point of putting i=0 exactly in front of bash?

Comment: @KvyatkovskySergey: Since the command runs in separate process, it has a different variable space than the main process. In order to inherit the `i` variable, we export it to the environment of the child process with `i=0 command`. If you initialize the variable as `loopValue='i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]; do make -j15 clean && make -j15; ((i++)); done'` then the export is not necessary

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to open a new process with `bash -c`. You can use a Bash function instead:

```
function loopVariable {
  for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $i; done
}

loopVariable
```

Please note that since no suprocess is created, you don't need to export your variables to use them in a child process as with a `bash -c`. All of them are available in the script scope.

**output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
loopvariable='for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $i; done'
bash -c "$loopvariable"
```